# Dice roll, estimator, epsilon

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, parameter-estimation

We roll a non-symmetric die. Let $X_n$ be the reulst of $n$-th roll. $$P(X_n = 6)= \frac{1}{6} + \varepsilon, \  P(X_n = 1) = \frac{1}{6} - \varepsilon, \ P(X_n=2) = ... = P(X_n = 5) = \frac{1}{6} $$

How can I find a consistent and unbiased estimator for parameter $\varepsilon$?

I thought I could introduce to other variables: $A_n =$number of $1$s in the first $n$ rolls and $B_n =$number of $6$s in the first $n$ rolls.

Then for $\overline{\alpha_n} = \frac{A_n+B_n}{n}$ we have:

$\mathbb{E}(\overline{\alpha_n}) = \frac{1}{n}( \mathbb{E}(A_n) + \mathbb{E}(B_n)) = \frac{1}{n} (n \cdot (\frac{1}{6} - \varepsilon) + n \cdot (\frac{1}{6} - \varepsilon)) = \frac{1}{6} - \varepsilon +\frac{1}{6} - \varepsilon =\frac{2}{3} - 2 \varepsilon$ and I should get $\epsilon$.

So I suppose I could instead write $\overline{\alpha_n} = \frac{2}{3}- \frac{A_n+B_n}{2n}$

But the variable $\overline{\alpha_n}$ isn't convergent almost surely or in probability to $\varepsilon$.

Could you tell me how to solve such problems?

I haven't been able to find anything on the web that would help me come up with estimators given specific kinds of events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_n$ be $+1$ if $X_n$ is $6$, $-1$ if $X_n$ is $1$ and $0$ in all other cases. Then
\begin{align*}
E(Y_n)&=1\left(\frac{1}{6}+e\right)+(-1)\left(\frac{1}{6}-e\right)=2e,\\
E(Y_n^2)&=1^2\left(\frac{1}{6}+e\right)+(-1)^2\left(\frac{1}{6}-e\right)=\frac{1}{3},
\end{align*}
and $V(Y_n)=\frac{1}{3}-4e^2$. Then, the estimator $\theta_n=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_n$ is unbiased and consistent for $e$. Checking for unbiasedness entails a straightforward application of linearity and because the variance is finite, you can use Chebyshev's inequality to prove consistency.

Comment: Or I could use strong law of large numbers, couldn't I? Then I have $\theta_n=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_n \to \frac{1}{2} EY_1 = \varepsilon$

Comment: So while solving such problems, we introduce new variables $Y_n$, which indicate the those outcomes of $X_n$  in  which parameter $\varepsilon$ is used, and then we compute their expected values. Then we decide sum them up and decide what to do with that sum in order for its expectation to give us $\varepsilon$. And if we'are dealing with a sum divided by number of elements, we get $E Y_n$ in its limit. Is that the way we do it?

Comment: @Hagrid You can certainly use any LLN you wish; I pointed out the Chebyshev's inequality because it's a more "elementary" way to prove consistency. My intuition for this problem is that: the $1-6$ actual outcomes for $X_n$ are just noise, all I cared was one outcome carries prob $1/6+e$, another $1/6-e$ and the rest $1/6$ each. From there, the definition for $Y_n$ as done above became very suggestive.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep that in mind :)